# How to integrate $1-\tan^4(x)$ without using secant?

Tags: calculus, integration

How to integrate such function:

$\int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3}1-\tan^4(x)$

I already found a solution using the trigonometric function secant. It looks like this:

$$u=\tan(x),\quad \frac{du}{dx}=\sec^2(x)$$

$$
\begin{align}
\int 1-\tan^4(x) & = \int 1 \;dx - \int\tan^4(x) \; dx \\

& = x-\int\tan^4(x) \; dx \\

& = x-\int\tan^2(x) \tan^2(x) \; dx \\

& = x-\int\tan^2(x) (\sec^2(x) - 1) \; dx \\

& = x-\int\tan^2(x) \sec^2(x) \; dx - \int\tan^2(x) \; dx \\

& = x-\int u^2 \; du - (\tan(x)-x) \\

& = x-\frac{1}{3}u^3 - (\tan(x)-x) \\

& = 2x-\frac{1}{3}\tan^3(x)-\tan(x)
\end{align}
$$

The only problem now is, that I have to find a solution without using secant. Can someone say me how to solve this without secant?

Comment: Can we use cosine instead? What does "without using secant" really mean?

Comment: cosine is ok. I'm not allowed to use secant, because it is not yet "officially" introduced in my math course.

Comment: +C$\phantom{\;\;\;\;\;\;\;}$

Comment: @Antauras: The indefinite integral of $1-\tan^4 x$ is $-(1/3)\tan^3 x +\tan x +C$. Just a minus sign error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use
$$
  \frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x} \tan(x) = 1 + \tan^2(x)
$$
Then
$$ \begin{eqnarray}
  \int \left(1-\tan^4(x)\right)\mathrm{d} x &=& \int \left(1-\tan^2(x)\right) \left(1+\tan^2(x)\right) \mathrm{d} x = \int \left(1-\tan^2(x)\right) \mathrm{d} \tan(x)\\  
&=& \tan(x) - \frac{1}{3} \tan^3(x) + \color{gray}{\text{const}}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Comment: How did you come to $(1-tan^2(x))(1+tan^2(x))$?. The latter is clear, but not the former.

Comment: $(a^2-b^2)=(a-b)(a+b)$

Comment: Binomial formula. Cool! One last question: How does the last step work (from $1-\tan^2(x)$ to $-(1/3)\tan^3(x)$)?

Comment: @Antonas $\int ( 1- \tan^2(x)) \mathrm{d} \tan(x) = \int \mathrm{d} \tan(x) - \int \tan^2(x) \mathrm{d} \tan(x) = \tan(x) - \frac{1}{3} \tan^3(x) + C$.

Comment: It is the $\int\tan^2(x)\mathrm{d}\tan(x)$ that make problems. Where does the $(1/3)$ come from?

Comment: @Antoras Compare this with $\int u^2 \mathrm{d} u = \frac{u^3}{3} + C$.

Comment: @Sasha: Ok, thanks. I got it.

Answer (score 5):

Sasha's solution is very elegant. However, if you can't see a trick like this, you can always mechanically integrate any rational function of sine and cosine using the [Weierstraß substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution).

With

$$\tan x=\frac{2t}{1-t^2}\;,$$

$$\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}=\frac2{1+t^2}\;,$$

$$t=\tan\frac x2\;,$$

the integral of $\tan^4 x$ becomes

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\int\tan^4x\mathrm dx
\\
&=&
\int\left(\frac{2t}{1-t^2}\right)^4\frac2{1+t^2}\mathrm dt
\\
&=&
\int\frac{32t^4}{(1-t^2)^4(1+t^2)}\mathrm dt
\\
&=&
\int\left(\frac2{t^2+1}-\frac1{(t-1)^2}-\frac1{(t+1)^2}+\frac1{(t-1)^3}-\frac1{(t+1)^3}+\frac1{(t-1)^4}+\frac1{(t+1)^4}\right)\mathrm dt
\\
&=&
2\arctan t+\frac1{t-1}+\frac1{t+1}-\frac1{2(t-1)^2}+\frac1{2(t+1)^2}-\frac1{3(t-1)^3}-\frac1{3(t+1)^3}+ \color{gray}{\text{const}}
\\
&=&
2\arctan t+\frac{2t}{t^2-1}-\frac{8t^3}{3(t^2-1)^3}+ \color{gray}{\text{const}}
\\
&=&
x-\tan x+\frac13\tan^3 x+ \color{gray}{\text{const}}\;,
\end{eqnarray}
$$

where I used Wolfram|Alpha for [pulling apart the fractions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=partial%20fractions%20for%20x%5E4/%28%281-x%5E2%29%5E4%281%2bx%5E2%29%29) and [putting them back together again](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-1%2F%282%28t-1%29%5E2%29%2B1%2F%282%28t%2B1%29%5E2%29-1%2F%283%28t-1%29%5E3%29-1%2F%283%28t%2B1%29%5E3%29).